# Getting 500 error with Grails 3.3.8 app using Tomcat ISAPI configuration with IIS 10

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, grails, isapi

I followed [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) guide to configure Tomcat 8.5.12 to run behind IIS 10 on a Windows 2016 server. After I deploy my Grails 3.3.8 app to Tomcat, I can access it at `http://hostname:8080/app_name/` through Tomcat directly, but I get a 500 error when I try to access it at `https://hostname/app_name/` when the request goes through IIS. The Tomcat /examples/ work fine at `https://hostname/examples/` so I know ISAPI is setup correctly.

The reason why I am doing this is 1) for SSL pass-through to Tomcat, and 2) because I have a .NET ERP application running on IIS that I am trying integrate the Grails app into in order to use the Grails Jasper Reports plug-in.

Is there a trick to get Grails 3.3.8 to work using a Tomcat ISAPI setup?